# So it sounds, good for you

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrases

> **Mom**: *"I've already spent all my money on your bedroom. I'm broke."*
> **Boy**: *"Uh, you're broke. Poor Frankie. What, What did you break?"*
> **Mom**: *"No, I haven't broken anything. Broke means I haven't got any money."*
> **Boy**: *"Well, I'm not broke. I've got lots of money."*
> **Mom**: *"`So it sounds`, good for you."*

---

What does "**So it sounds**" mean?

Comment: where did you find this conversation? Can you provide a link?

Comment: What a horrid child!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context "so it sounds" means "*apparently*".

Take a look at [this link](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/so-it-is-so-there-are-so-i-have-etc).

Variations of this include:

- So it appears
- So it is

"So it sounds" is used when the evidence presented has been perceived aurally.

Comment: Is "So it seems" a synonym for "So it sounds"?

Comment: *Seem* is more general - it's how you perceive things, and you can do that by seeing things, hearing things, observing patterns, etc. So you can definitely use it instead of *sounds*, yes, it just loses that more specific sense of "so I've heard (from you or others)"